# How to make use of Point sprite in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I am tring to draw  Point Sprite in cocos2D with texture.

then how to pass the point size into program_ and vertexShader? I find the attributes are only 3 kind, how to use a new attribute?

## define kCCAttributeNameColor           @"a_color"

## define kCCAttributeNamePosition        @"a_position"

## define kCCAttributeNameTexCoord        @"a_texCoord"

many thanks!

Comment: if you are trying to make a particle system you may want to take a look [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:particles)

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but if you want to know how to change the size of the particles, you can use the properties startSize and endSize

Comment: yes, I'am a new comer in Cocos2D.sorry for mistake